# Is this FizzBuzz code idiomatic Groovy?

Tags: programming-challenge, unit-testing, fizzbuzz, groovy

I'm new to Groovy but have some experience with Java, C and Python. I'd appreciate your feedback on Groovy style and features in this FizzBuzz code.

**Review Checklist**

- Is it idiomatic Groovy code?
- Can anything be taken away?
- Can it be more functional?
- Could I make use of any Groovy-specific features?

**FizzBuzzTest.groovy**

```
import org.fizzbuzz.FizzBuzz
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class FizzBuzzTest {

    FizzBuzz fb

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        fb = new FizzBuzz()
    }

    @Test
    void testGiven1Returns1AsString() {
        assert '1' == fb.toString(1)
    }

    @Test
    void testGiven2Returns2AsString() {
        assert '2' == fb.toString(2)
    }

    @Test
    void testGiven3ReturnsFizz() {
        assert 'Fizz' == fb.toString(3)
    }

    @Test
    void testGiven5ReturnsBuzz() {
        assert 'Buzz' == fb.toString(5)
    }

    @Test
    void testGiven15ReturnsFizzBuzz() {
        assert 'FizzBuzz' == fb.toString(15)
    }
}
```

**FizzBuzz.groovy**

```
package org.fizzbuzz

class FizzBuzz {

    String toString(number) {
        if (isMultipleOf3(number) && isMultipleOf5(number))
            return 'FizzBuzz'
        if (isMultipleOf3(number))
            return 'Fizz'
        if (isMultipleOf5(number))
            return 'Buzz'
        number.toString()
    }

    private boolean isMultipleOf5(number) {
        isMultipleOf.curry(5)(number)
    }

    private boolean isMultipleOf3(number) {
        isMultipleOf.curry(3)(number)
    }

    private def isMultipleOf = { int multipleOf, number ->
        number % multipleOf == 0
    }

    static void main(String... args) {
        def fb = new FizzBuzz()
        for (num in 1..100) {
            println fb.toString(num)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code should follow the principle of least surprise, so language features should be used to increase clarity.  I don't really see particular clarity in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a straightforward method:

```
private boolean isMultipleOf3(number) {
    isMultipleOf(3, number)
}
```

Or you could define it as a partial method:

```
private def isMultipleOf3 = isMultipleOf.curry(3)
```

But what you wrote is unnecessarily complicated:

> ```
> private boolean isMultipleOf3(number) {
>     isMultipleOf.curry(3)(number)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Referring to 'Could I make use of any Groovy-specific features?':
You could use a Category to add a isMultipleOf() method to Integer. So you could write `if (number.isMultipleOf3())`
(see [Groovy Goodness: Use Categories to Add Functionality to Classes](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-use-categories-to-add.html))

```
class Multiple {
    static boolean isMultipleOf(Integer number, int multipleOf) {
        number % multipleOf == 0
    }
}

def foo = 5
use (Multiple) {
    if(foo.isMultipleOf(3))
        println "Fizz"
    else
        println "Buzz"
}
```